# Why does does the body of my while statement not print even though the condition is true in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am writing a program that displays the numbers where the user decides the numbers per line, but the number has to be between 10 and 30 although for whatever reason the while statement doesn't execute even if the condition is true. for example if I input the number 5 it should output "Number must be between 10 and 30" but instead it outputs 1 to 1000 with 5 numbers per line.

Below is my code, any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated

```
count = 0
X = int(input('please enter a number:'))

while X <=10 and X >=30:
        print('Number must be between 10 and 30')
    
else:
    for number in range (1, 1000, 1):
            print(number,' ', end = '')
            count = count + 1
            if count == X:
                print()
                count = 0
```

Comment: what number do you know of thats less than or equal to 10 and greater than or equal to 30?

Comment: how can x be less than 10 and also more than 30? do you mean while x is between 10 and 30?

Comment: Based on your text print, why not write `while 10 <= x <= 30:`?

Comment: Python supports this syntax: `while 10 <= X <= 30:` - but you probably want it to be `while X <= 10 or X >= 30` (Ignoring the fact that you do not ask the user for inputs again in the loop)

Comment: I recommend trying rubber duck debugging. It sounds dumb but it probably would have solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone I solved the problem with an 
OR statement

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the condition in while loop by using "OR" logical operator ,because the error message needs to be printed for either number<=10 or number>=30 conditions.

while X <=10 or X >=30:
print('Number must be between 10 and 30')